# sfml window event polling is really slow

Tags: performance, events, sfml, polling

(I am using Codeblocks on Debian Linux with the GNU GCC Compiler)

I created a game with sfml and everything works really well unless i implement the usual

```
    while (window->pollEvent(event)){
    //optional code
    }
```

loop.

I have tried the same code on Windows with MS Visual Studio and it worked perfectly fine. The game still laggs a lot even when I only execute the

```
    window->pollEvent(event);
```

line only once, even if there is no event at all. Why does that line of code take so much time? (It takes as much time as about 10 frames would take without it).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing window.pollEvent(event) instead of window->pollEvent, I have never seen this form of using pollEvent until now..